# ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-00907

I'm getting the error " ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis"
but I've checked and all the parenthesis are there, so I'm stumped.

My query is

```
SELECT 
  SUM(score) as score, 
  facebook_id, 
  firstname, 
  lastname, 
  dense_rank(score) 
WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY score ) as rank_db  
FROM 
  (
    SELECT DISTINCT *
    FROM 
      (
        SELECT *  
        FROM fanta_score 
        ORDER BY score desc
      ) as f 
    GROUP BY 
      facebook_id, game_id
  ) as g 
GROUP BY facebook_id
ORDER BY score DESC, created_at
LIMIT 50
```

I'm by no means an Oracle expert, but I have to use it due the hosting environment its has to be in.

Comment: I'm thinking it might be something to do with the limit statement???

Comment: Have you tried commenting out each piece of the query (working inside/out) and seeing which statement in particular generates the error?

Comment: Also, this doesn't really solve your problem, but you don't want to have an ORDER clause in a subquery.  That will kill your query performance because the optimizer can no longer use indexes once you sort because it has to flatten the result set.  People will often ORDER in a subquery when they really don't need to ORDER.

Comment: yea, i'm working through that now, but I don't have a local oracle test environment so it is a tedious process.

Comment: `distinct *` and `GROUP BY facebook_id, game_id` in the same select doesn't make sense. Additionally the outer statement won't work, as you are not grouping by all non-aggregate columns.

Answer (score 0):

LIMIT command isn't recognized in Oracle. And should use **ROWNUM** instead of **Limit**.

```
SELECT 
  SUM(score) as score, 
  facebook_id, 
  firstname, 
  lastname, 
  dense_rank(score) 
WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY score ) as rank_db  
FROM 
  (
    SELECT DISTINCT *
    FROM 
      (
        SELECT *  
        FROM fanta_score 
        ORDER BY score desc
      ) as f 
    GROUP BY 
      facebook_id, game_id
  ) as g
WHERE ROWNUM = 50 
GROUP BY facebook_id
ORDER BY score DESC, created_at
```

Comment: I'm guessing that should be rownum <= 50? Your query as written will return zero rows, right?

Comment: Thanks, I removed the limit completely and I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Probably, you can specify like that but no problem if you want to put as **ROWNUM=50**

Comment: Can you remove "dense_rank(score) WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY score ) as rank_db" and try it again?

Comment: So I've stripped it right back and now getting a different error.
 ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
New query is;
SELECT SUM(score) as score, facebook_id, firstname, lastname FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT * FROM fanta_score GROUP BY facebook_id, game_id) as g GROUP BY facebook_id ORDER BY score DESC, created_at

Comment: have you forgot to remove "comma" after lastname?

Comment: Currently I don't have PL/SQL at my office pc that's why cannot help you.

Comment: there are lots of problems with this query. You have columns that you aren't grouping by (firstname, lastname), you're using an alias in the order by (should be sum(score)), we can't tell whether your subquery is valid or not because of the "select *", and what's this use of a distinct and group by in the same query, anyway? Needs some work, but I'm not sure where to start.

Comment: @ppshein: PL/SQL is only for stored procedures. But you can easily test Oracle SQL here: http://sqlfiddle.com